# Combination of search result($query String) with added $args does not show all posts

Tags: wordpress

Below code is combination of search result($query String) with added $args.

$all_num_normal (counted posts quantity) says its **5 posts** as I expected.  However, when I foreach title of posts, it shows only 3 titles.  print_r also shows only 3 posts information.

When I search same keyword by regular search function, it shows 5 posts(its hit any of title, text, category name or meta value).

```
<?php
global $query_string;
$args = $query_string;
parse_str( $args, $args );
$args_normal = $args + array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'category_name' => $shop_name,
'category__not_in' => array( 3, 137, 571 ),
'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key'=> '2a',
                    'value' => array('2020-02-01' , $week),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                    ), 
                    ), 

);
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $args_normal, TRUE ) . '</pre>';
$query = new WP_Query($args_normal);
$all_num_normal = $query->found_posts;
?>

<?php
//Must be 5 titles, but its only 3 titles shown
$my_posts = get_posts($args_normal);
//print_r shows information of 3 posts

if ( $my_posts ) {
foreach( $my_posts as $post ) {
echo get_the_title( $post->ID);

}}
?>
```

print_r shows below text.

```
Array
(
    [s] => rabbit
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [category_name] => atsugi
    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 137
            [2] => 571
        )

    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 2a
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2020-02-01
                            [1] => 2020-07-20
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => DATE
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This appears to be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62842927/foreach-does-not-work-correctly-some-posts-are-skipped-in-args-that-are-combin) that you posted the day before. Please don’t re-post the same questions. If you have new information to add, you can edit the existing question using the ‘edit’ link under the question.

Comment: I deleted question posted yesterday.  Thank you

Comment: The search function isn't necessary here, since it doesn't really help us. Also, don't `print_r` inside of the `foreach` loop. Try `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $my_posts, TRUE ) . '</pre>';` immediately after  `$my_posts = get_posts( $args_normal )` and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you disinfor.  I try it now.

Comment: Hi disinfor  Now above code shows 3 posts.  Some posts are still ignored.

Comment: I found that those ignored posts contain key word only in their category name.  So, when I write key word on post title, the posts are not ignored.  I like to have those ignored posts in $args_normal, like regular search result without key word in title.

Comment: Edit this question to include what you get from this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $args_normal, TRUE ) . '</pre>';` - Put that right above `$query = new WP....`

Comment: Thank you for your time disinfor.  Now I editted the question with print_r  and its result.

Comment: Disinfor, thank you for using your time for my question.  Now I got right answer.  I set 'suppress_filters' => false , and then filtering starts to work.  I do appreciate your help these days.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set **'suppress_filters' => false,** and then filtering started correctly.
Regarding 'suppress_filters,' get_post function has default parameter "true", and it means filtering is not enable.